# Prove that if $T$ is tournament that is not transitive then $T$ has at least three hamiltonian paths.

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Prove that if $T$ is tournament that is not transitive then $T$ has at least three hamiltonian paths.

Proof:
I am not sure how to start this proof. If it is not transitive then I think the tournament will be a hamiltonian. So that if $(a,b),(b,c),(c,a)$ if $a,b,c$ are the vertex in a cycle. So then you would have $3$ hamiltonian path. And a Hamiltoian path start and one vertex and ends at another and contains all the vertices.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "If it is not transitive then I think the tournament will be a hamiltonian." Are you saying that a non-transitive tournament will have a Hamiltonian **cycle**? That is false. The tournament with vertices $a,b,c,d$ and directed adges $ab,bc,ca,ad,bd,cd$ is neither transitive nor stronly connected.

Comment: On the other hand, if you know that any tournament is the "transitive sum" of its strong components, then for the proof of your theorem it will suffice to show that every strongly connected tournament with more than one vertex has at least three Hamiltonian paths. And I guess you already know that every strongly connected tournament with more than one vertex has a Hamiltonian cycle?

Comment: Yes I know I think there is theorem which says  A nontrivial tournament T is Hamiltonian only if its its strong. But here it says only that T is nontransitive

Comment: Right. So decompose $T$ into its **strong components**. At least one of the strong components is non trivial (has more than one vertex), so it has a Hamiltonian cycle, so it has at least as many Hamiltonian paths as vertices, so at least $3.$ Now get a Hamiltonian path in $T$ by choosing a Hamiltonian path in each of its strong component and putting them together.

Answer (score 1):

1-Any tournament contains an odd number of hamiltonian directed paths.

2-$T$ is a transitive tournament if and only if it has only $1$ hamiltonian directed path.